# Zoom on Image in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, image, xaml

I've got a method that zooms in and out on an image in WPF. It looks like this:

```
private void onMouseWheel_Scroll(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
    var position = e.MouseDevice.GetPosition(CctvImage);

    var renderTransformValue = CctvImage.RenderTransform.Value;
    if (e.Delta > 0)
        renderTransformValue.ScaleAtPrepend(1.1, 1.1, position.X, position.Y);
    else
        renderTransformValue.ScaleAtPrepend(1 / 1.1, 1 / 1.1, position.X, position.Y);

    CctvImage.RenderTransform = new MatrixTransform(renderTransformValue);
}
```

This works fine for zooming in and I like the functionality of zooming in where the mouse is specifically on the screen.

However, when zooming out the user is able to zoom out past the point of the image taking up the screen. This means it's very difficult to get back to the images original position taking up the full Window. They are able to get to the point where either large parts of the image are not on the screen or where there are large amounts of whitespace, this is an example of what I am describing:

[image]

As you can see the image is tiny on the screen whereas I would like to prevent the user from zooming out further than the point that the image takes up the whole window.

Is there a way I can implement this?

Answer (score 2):

How about resetting the transform before and keeping your own "scale" value that you can check against a "max scale" and a "min scale", something like this:

```
    double scale = 1.0;
    double minScale = 0.5;
    double maxScale = 2.0;

    private void image_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
    {
        // back to normal (maybe this isn't needed since we're making a new one below anyway)
        CctvImage.RenderTransform = null;

        var position = e.MouseDevice.GetPosition(CctvImage);

        if (e.Delta > 0)
            scale += 0.1;
        else
            scale -= 0.1;

        if (scale > maxScale)
            scale = maxScale;
        if (scale < minScale)
            scale = minScale;

        CctvImage.RenderTransform = new ScaleTransform(scale, scale, position.X, position.Y);


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to prevent the `Image` from being zoomed out from its original size, right? Then you should make sure that the scale is never less than `1`:

```
double currentScale = 1.0;
private void onMouseWheel_Scroll(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
    var position = e.MouseDevice.GetPosition(CctvImage);
    var renderTransformValue = CctvImage.RenderTransform.Value;
    if (e.Delta > 0)
    {
        currentScale += 0.1;
    }
    else if (e.Delta < 0)
    {
        currentScale -= 0.1;
        if (currentScale < 1.0)
            currentScale = 1.0;
    }
    CctvImage.RenderTransform = new ScaleTransform(currentScale, currentScale, position.X, position.Y);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone wants like I did, that the image stays in the center while you zoom the image, you can do it by writing the RenderTransform so it becomes something like this:

```
    double scale    = 1.0;
    double minScale = 0.5;
    double maxScale = 10.0;

    private void image_MouseWheel(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseWheelEventArgs e)
    {
        Image image = (Image)sender;

        if (e.Delta > 0)
            scale += 0.1;
        else
            scale -= 0.1;

        if (scale > maxScale)
            scale = maxScale;
        if (scale < minScale)
            scale = minScale;

        image.RenderTransform =
            new ScaleTransform(scale, scale,
                image.RenderSize.Width / 2,
                image.RenderSize.Height / 2);
    }
```